# Convert string of dates with 'th' 'st' 'rd' 'nd' into date format via python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am scrapping a website for the dates using beautiful soup. Here is the CSS

```
<div id="listing-details-list">
<h3 class="listing-details-header">
Details:
<span>Posted on: 14th June 2016</span>
</h3>
</div>
```

The code I am using for getting the date is this

```
# date
    try:
        date=soup.find("h3","listing-details-header") 
        date_result= str(date.get_text().encode("utf-8").strip()[20:])
        print "\nPublished date: ", date_result
    except StandardError as e:
        date_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print date_result
```

Results I am getting is a date as a string. Some samples are

```
23rd June 2016
21st July 2016
20th July 2016
3rd July 2016
```

Now, I want the date to be a proper date with the format 'type' like below so that i can do computation on it

```
23/6/2016
21/7/2016
20/7/2016
3/7/2016
```

What approach is the best in my code to get the desired date?

I want the a date to be saved in such a manner:

```
Month= 6
Day = 23
Year = 2016
```

---

I tried the solution marked as best answer and it works

```
try:
        date=soup.find("h3","listing-details-header") 
        date_result= str(date.get_text().encode("utf-8").strip()[20:])
        date_result=parse(date_result) #added
        month = date_result.month
        day = date_result.day
        year = date_result.year
        print month
        print day
        print year

        print "\nPublished date: ", date_result
    except StandardError as e:
        date_result="Error was {0}".format(e)
        print date_result
```

Comment: "I tried the solution marked as best answer and it works" – *and* you marked it as 'accepted', so it's clear to everyone that particular solution worked for you. There is no need to repeat the answer in your post. If you think your own answer is sufficiently different from the one offered, you can always add it *as a separate answer*.

Comment: Thanks., i ll keep a note of it. im new here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To parse the dates I would just let the [`dateutil` parser](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) do the job:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> l = ["23rd June 2016", "21st July 2016", "20th July 2016", "3rd July 2016"]
>>> for item in l:
...     parse(item)
... 
datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 23, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 21, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 20, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 3, 0, 0)
```

You get the `datetime` instances which you can use to do date or time related computations on.

I would also improve the way you locate the desired elements on the page and extract the dates:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div id="listing-details-list">
<h3 class="listing-details-header">
Details:
<span>Posted on: 14th June 2016</span>
</h3>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for item in soup.find_all("span", text=lambda text: text and text.startswith("Posted on:")):
    date_string = item.get_text().split(": ")[-1]
    print(parse(date_string))
```

Comment: Thanks. I installed the module and it works perfectly. I actually needed to save the date, month and year in separate variables day, month, year. possible?

Comment: @Joanne sure, you can access the `.day`, `.month`, `.year` properties of a datetime object.

Comment: Tried. plz check my edited answer. there is a error. seems like datetime is not defined?

Comment: @Joanne `month= datetime.month(date_result)` should be `month = date_result.month`, that's what alecxe said.